# (beginner) angular binding issues

Tags: angular, binding, syntax-error

i've started really fresh just with coding.
and i find myself stuck on probably something verry simple.
im doing assignments from out a book
it litterly tells me what to do, and it doesnt work.
[(screenshot of the book).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mt1zH.jpg)
written in Dutch, so i translate:

" place `<app-camping-registratie (campingRegistratieCreate)="onCampingRegistratieCreated($event)"></app-camping-registratie>` in page app.component.html "

before adding code mentioned above it works & looks like this:
[screenshot localhost:4200](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfxaH.jpg)

and when added i get these errors:
[image errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmAXB.jpg)

*index.js:493 [webpack-dev-server] ERROR
app/app.component.html:5:82 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'Event' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
5 <app-camping-registratie (campingRegistratieCreate)="onCampingRegistratieCreated($event)">
~~~~~~
app/app.component.ts:5:16
5   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.*

refering to these codes:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  campings: string[] = ['De Karnemelkplaats', 'Tro Do Way', 'Camping Kohnenhof', 'Camping Langewald', 'Camping La Fouly'];
registratie: string[] = ['Jaap']

  onCampingCreated(name: string) {
    this.campings.push(name);
  }
  onCampingRegistratieCreated(name: string){
    this.registratie.push(name);
  }
  }
```

**[IMG| app.component.ts]**(https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ud2F.png)

```
<app-camping-invoer (campingCreate)="onCampingCreated($event)"> 
</app-camping-invoer>
<app-camping [campingList]="campings"></app-camping>
<br><br>
<app-camping [campingRegistratieList]="registratie"></app-camping>  
<app-camping-registratie(campingRegistratieCreate)="onCampingRegistratieCreated($event)"></app-camping-registratie>
```

**[IMG| app.component.html]**(https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBuAY.png)

[link to stackblitz for the entire script](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-kqzhdv?file=src%2Fmain.ts%3Elink%20to%20stackblitz)

perhaps i'm really dumb for not understanding the error thats given,
but i really can't figure out the issue here.
much apreciated if someone could advice & explain whats going on here so i could learn from it.

i redid the entire assignment multiple times. and even continued, ignoring the error.
[according to the book these are supposed to be all the codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeWqG.png)

-Berry

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Please add your code and error messages as text, not as pictures. Also add all necessary information in your question instead of referring to the comments.

Answer (score 0):

So it does state in the error message and within your code, that your function onCampingRegistratieCreated is expecting a string as argument. $event is not a string, but an object, that does need additional solving/extraction of data.

One option would be to rewrite the function to look like this:

```
onCampingRegistratieCreated(event: Event) {
   ... // event.? <-- whatever info your would like to push
}
```

Another workaround is to set the actual string you want to push to that function within your template like this:

```
<app-camping-registratie(campingRegistratieCreate)="onCampingRegistratieCreated('Your String')"></app-camping-registratie>
```

Hope this helps. Good luck!